# Modifying text labels on top ggplot percentage barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I am trying to generate a grouped barplot with percentage count on the y-axis and text on the top of each bar that represent its value

My code is below:

```
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..) * 100), width = 0.7) + 
  labs(x = "Hours Worked 48 or more", y = "% of Employees", fill = "Hours Worked 48 or more", title = "Post-Legislation") + 
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "blue")) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = (..count..)/sum(..count..) * 100, y = ..prop..), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

I want the **text to be white, accurate to 1dp, and placed at the top of each bar**.

I have been trying to different codes, but can't get the desired result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the data snippet:

```
structure(list(year = c("2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018"), hours.48 = c("Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No")), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Would be great if you could add a data snippet as well to make it fully reproducable. See `dput`.

Comment: @coffeinjunky I have done this now.

Comment: See my suggested attempt below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

positions = df %>% group_by(hours.48) %>% summarise(prop=n()/nrow(df)*100)
```

Note I am precomputing the labels = positions here. Given your example data, there aren't any decimals, but you can format the values you would like to see here if you want to go down this route. Personally, I prefer precomputing everything I want to plot to separate responsibilities.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=hours.48, fill=hours.48)) +
geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..) * 100), width = 0.7) + 
  labs(x = "Hours Worked 48 or more", y = "% of Employees", fill = "Hours Worked 48 or more", title = "Post-Legislation") + 
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "blue")) + 
  geom_text(data=positions, aes(label = prop, y = prop), colour='white', stat= "identity", vjust = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

You can also simplify this even more by just querying `positions` as dataframe instead of the original `df` by using the following two lines instead of the corresponding ones above:

```
ggplot(positions, aes(x=hours.48, fill=hours.48)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = prop), width = 0.7, stat='identity') +
```

Comment: If you want to add % instead of the whole numbers?

Comment: @user3571389: please see my answer with %.

Comment: Just use `label = paste0(prop, "%")` instead of `label=prop`. @user3571389

Comment: In the call to `geom_text`, that is.

Answer (score 1):

With your original dataset and with `scales` package you could do:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(hours.48), fill=as.factor(hours.48))) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
    geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), 
                  label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
              stat = "count", vjust = 2, color="white") +
    labs(x = "Hours Worked 48 or more", y = "% of Employees", fill = "Hours Worked 48 or more", title = "Post-Legislation") + 
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "blue")) + 
    theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]